# Datetime formats automatically on Email

Tags: c#

I am creating a module that sends a message about their transactions on the system.

However, when I try to include the Datetime `(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())` output, it is formatted automatically. (For example, my entry on the code is 02142013_023345, on my email it becomes 02/14/20132:33 PM)

Are there formats that I need to consider when dealing with DateTime on Emails?

- Edit *

*Thanks a lot for the assistance guys.
What I did is, followed your suggestions and reformatted my Datetime variable.
Also, I rechecked on the final value of my "DateTime variable" that was being passed on my email function.
Reformatted it correctly and there, my problem was fixed.
Thanks for the links and guides also, I've added them to my reference.*

Comment: Not a question yet - `ToShortDateString` does what is suppsed to do - format date to readable culture specific string. Not sure what else you expect from that function, or if you need something else (i.e. looking for correct custom format string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` will return you a string formatted based on your Current Thread's Culture Information.

If you have info about your users Culture, you can use that to edit the Current Culture Info.

Follow this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime.ToString(string format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx). Also [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement which ever format you want to use for your emails. if your code has `02142013_023345`, *(which is month first then day, then year)*,  then you can use specify the custom format in the `ToString`

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

For more formats see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)